# phpBB help: Hide 'views' and 'replies' column on the forum view page

Tags: php, phpbb3

I am new to PHP. I am trying to hide total number of 'Views' and 'Replies' column on the forum view page. I am not sure what all changes would be required.

My working environment consists of  phpBB v3.0.0 and MySQL v4.1.1. Would appreciate any help or inputs.

Best Regards,

Gaurav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i wrote a hack for a phpbb once, but right now i dont really know much about phpbb and how it works exacty.
But if your lucky, you just have to delete the two columns in a html-template. Just take a look at the html files, if something looks like the page you want to change and try a little around with that.

If that does not work, i would recommend asking in a phpbb forum

Comment: Hey, Thanks for help. I got it resolved through phpBB Support. I will post the link here for other's reference. 

Link: http://www.phpbb.com/community/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=1694935

Thanks once again.